# SQL Query : each Rep has max Invoice ID,how to return all invoices lower than each Reps max Invoiceid (per RepID)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with a row for each representative, and the ID of his/her latest Invoice

```
RepID   MaxInvoiceID
1            5000
2            5200
3            4800
```

How can I return all invoices where the InvoiceID is less than that specific Representatives MaxInvoiceID?

It would be one query that equates :

```
select * from Invoices where RepID= 1 and InvoiceID < 5000
union
select * from Invoices where RepID= 2 and InvoiceID < 5200
union
select * from Invoices where RepID= 3 and InvoiceID < 4800
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [`CROSS APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx). Assuming that the table with the list of all representatives is called `Reps`.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    Reps
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM Invoices
        WHERE
            Invoices.RepID = Reps.ID
            AND Invoices.InvoiceID < Reps.MaxInvoiceID
    ) AS CA
;
```

> [Using `APPLY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx)
>
> Both the left and right operands of the `APPLY` operator are
>   table expressions. The main difference between these operands is that
>   the *right_table_source* can use a table-valued function that takes a
>   column from the *left_table_source* as one of the arguments of the
>   function. The *left_table_source* can include table-valued functions,
>   but it cannot contain arguments that are columns from the
>   *right_table_source*.
>
> The `APPLY` operator works in the following way to
>   produce the table source for the `FROM` clause:
>
> 1. Evaluates *right_table_source* against each row of the *left_table_source* to
>      produce rowsets. The values in the *right_table_source* depend on
>      *left_table_source*. *right_table_source* can be represented approximately
>      this way: `TVF(left_table_source.row)`, where `TVF` is a table-valued
>      function.
> 2. Combines the result sets that are produced for each row in
>      the evaluation of *right_table_source* with the *left_table_source* by
>      performing a `UNION ALL` operation. The list of columns produced by the
>      result of the `APPLY` operator is the set of columns from the
>      *left_table_source* that is combined with the list of columns from the
>      *right_table_source*.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT I.*
FROM Invoices I
   INNER JOIN Reps R  -- Assuming table contains (RepID, MaxInvoiceID) called Reps
      ON I.RepID = R.RepID
WHERE I.InvoiceID < R.MaxInvoiceID
```